# echo for style in table row and table data

Tags: php

```
<tr <?php if($isOverDeadline)
    {
      echo ' style="background-color:#CC3300"';
    }
  ?>><td width="250" <?php
      if($isOverDeadline)
      {
    echo ' style="color:#fff"';
      }
      ?>><?php echo $something; ?> </td></tr>
```

I find that the nested php blocks inside tr and td do not work. Could someone tell me what is wrong ?

Comment: What doesn't work? What does the output HTML look like?  You're missing semicolons on the style rules, but that shouldn't break the markup.

Comment: so is there no output at all or is the php not interpreted or how exactly do you know it doesn't work?

Comment: As a point of advice, it's usually better to assign a CSS class rather than put in inline style attributes. `if ($isOverDeadline) { echo ' class="over"'; }`

Comment: I would like to decorate a row in the table if the project deadline is over. and I guess the php is not interpreted.

Comment: Post the result html, or at least this area of it.

Comment: Do a var_dump on $isOverDeadline, check and make sure its the expected value.

Answer (score 1):

**Check whether isOverDeadline is true or false **

```
<?php $isOverDeadline = true; ?>
<tr <?php if($isOverDeadline)
    {
      echo ' style="background-color:#CC3300"';
    }
  ?>><td width="250" <?php
      if($isOverDeadline)
      {
    echo ' style="color:#fff"';
      }
      ?>><?php echo $something; ?> </td></tr>
```

Comment: I agree with this answer, I'm guessing "$isOverDeadline" is always returning false for some reason, use this to check if it works when you force true, and then figure out why it's not returning true when expected.

Comment: when you use variables in condition,you need to know the return value,in the above case only we can have Boolean values. so to say when it returns false put an else condition display some other colors .. here i have given an force true,it can also be false for that you need to put an else condition

Answer (score 1):

What I've typically done in the past, to avoid such possible issues is:

```
<?php

    // This is merely a convenience method for short circuiting,
    // you could use print() as it always returns 1, however e()
    // is just shorter.
    function e($arg)
    {
        echo $arg;
        return true;
    }

    $isOverDeadline = true;
    $something = "Hello world";

?>

<tr style="<?php $isOverDeadline and e('background-color: #cc3300;'); ?>">
    <td style="<?php $isOverDeadline and e('background-color: #ffffff;'); ?>" 
        width="250"><?php e($something); ?></td>
</tr>
```

This uses [short circuit evaluation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation) to minimize inlined PHP. As you can see, some IDEs or syntax hilighters will barf on it, but I run NetBeans and it looks good.

Keep in mind, my example will result in empty style attributes when `$isOverDeadline` is false, but you can modify as necessary (*the generating code looks cleaner without having to deal with prepending spaces, etc.*)

You can even replicate `else`:

```
<tr style="background-color: <?php ($isOverDeadline and e('#f00')) or e('#0ff'); ?>"></tr>
```

Which will be red on true, cyan on false.

Answer (score 0):

You should escape the double quotes like this
    echo ' style=\"background-color:#CC3300\"';

Comment: Why escape the double quotes?

Comment: And why wouldn't they be inserted without escaping them? The outer quotes are single quotes...

Comment: I've never had to escape them, are you sure?

Comment: As long as the outer quotes are single quotes you don't have to escape the inner double quotes, and that page doesn't say anything about the matter.

Comment: Uh, impartial observer here. There's **no point** in escaping the double quotes in this scenario.

Comment: You only need to escape the delimiting characters of a string literal. If you use single quotes, doubles don't need to be escaped, and vice versa. `echo '""' . "''";` is perfectly valid syntax, and will output as expected (*that being `""''`*)